# Lightbox issue on a website using Bootstrap & Flexslider

Tags: javascript, css

On this page http://www.dreamsmedia.org/dishagroup/machinery-equipment-maintenance-division.html I am using prettyPhoto lightbox inside FlexSlider.

The site is built using twitter Bootstrap.

I have tried all options but am unable to make any lightbox plugin work. Can you please check by clicking on the sliding images on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call prettyPhoto

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
```